# How to find number of specific column in csv using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This is my csv file.

[image]

Iam uploading this data to db using python pandas.How to find the number of fee columns are there(fee_1,fee_2,fee_3)?. Because the start,end,fee columns are dynamic. I need to upload based on the number of fee columns.

If number of fee columns is 2 means i need to upload this,

"slot_fee":[{"start": i['Start_1'],"end": i['End_1'],"fee": i['Fee_1']},{"start": i['Start_2'],"end": i['End_2'],"fee": i['Fee_2']}]

If it is 3 means i need to upload this,and so on.

"slot_fee":[{"start": i['Start_1'],"end": i['End_1'],"fee": i['Fee_1']},{"start": i['Start_2'],"end": i['End_2'],"fee": i['Fee_2']},{"start": i['Start_3'],"end": i['End_3']]

Can anyone help me with the python pandas code for this?

Comment: You may want to look at formatting your question better for clarity:
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly this might help :

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Fee_')]
```

it gives you the list of columns that start with Fee_, if you want the last one you can add

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Fee_')][-1]
```

Comment: It is giving only  this output. Index([], dtype='object')

Comment: can you upload an example of the dataframe i can reproduce ? @rovoda

Comment: I have added the dataframe above. Need the number of  fee columns.